# iPhone Data Structure and accessor code advice

Tags: iphone, data-structures

I need a code based solution for storing the following data without using CoreData. Preferably I would be able to access each row based on it's index, and each data field using a key/pair perhaps?

The PHP equivalent of what I'm looking for would be something like;

```
echo $arr[0]['Image'];
Apple.png
```

[image]

Comment: -1 "This question does not show [any research effort](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html)..."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` objects.

NSMutableArray has a `-writeToURL:` method you can use to save it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either plist, sqlite or Any other data storage take look at this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_store-data/). and if you are using like Sqlite than select query will get the `Apple.png`.